# Is there any possible way for LLVM to generate .bc file while generating .o file?

Tags: linux-kernel, llvm, llvm-clang

I am tring to build linux kernel using clang/llvm. I am trying to save the .bc file while generating the .o file . I find LLVM have the API "writebitcodetofile" whcich can save the bc code to certain file, but I am not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of flags that can do that for you:

- `-flto` enables Link-time optimization, which uses LLVM bitcode. In this case (almost) all the `.o` files will in fact contain the bitcode.
- `-save-temps` tells clang to put the results of each intermediate phase into a separate file. Simple `clang -save-temps main.c` may output `main.o`, `main.bc`, `main.i`, `main.s`, or object file, bitcode file, preprocessed file, and assembly file, respectively.
- `-fembed-bitcode` tells clang to include the bitcode representation of a file into the resulting object file. You can learn more about this here: https://jonasdevlieghere.com/libebc-ebcutil/

Note, however, that you won't get bitcode for assembly files.